# way i cant download eclipse on my computer the eclips dont run

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, download, 64-bit

I'm trying to download the eclipse platform and the text that shows is "the required java 64-bit java 1.8.0 virtual machine is not found"

what do I need to do? 
how I can solve that problem and start to develop

Comment: you have to download and install java first https://java.com/en/download/help/windows_manual_download.xml

Comment: @prhmma java.com provides only Java 8 JREs. In contrast, [AdoptOpenJDK.net](https://adoptopenjdk.net/index.html) provides Java 8, 11 and 13 JREs and JDKs.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to install java. Search on google "how to install java".

Comment: ok, I download the JAVA ide from eclipse site and its works! thanks!